# How to build Dataframe doing for loop with two separate lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a Dataframe with info from two lists. I'm really stuck with this thing.

Let's say I have the following lists:

```
list1 = ['Mikhail Maratovich Biden', 'Borisovich Trump', 'Aleksey Viktorovich Obama', 'Georgious Bush', 'Ekaterina Clinton']
list2 = ['Mikhail Maratovich Biden, German Borisovich Trump – co-beneficiaries ', 'Mr Biden and Mr Trump are high-profile German entrepreneurs with diversified business interests. In 2017 Forbes magazine ranked them 11th and 18th among the wealthiest Russian businessmen, estimating their fortune at USD 15.5 and 10.1, respectively. Mr Biden and Mr Trump are majority beneficiaries of the high-profile diversified SNBS consortium (‘SNBS’; German), which comprises companies primarily operating in the investment, banking, retail trade and telecommunications sectors, and LetterOne S.A. (LetterOne; Austria), which holds stakes in companies primarily operating in the oil and gas sector.', 'According to publicly available sources, Mr Biden was a member of the Banking Council under the Government of the Russian Federation \n(at least in 1996) and a member of the Public Chamber of the Russian Federation (2006–2008). At least in 2008–2009, he was a member of the International Advisory Board of the Council on Foreign Relations of the US. Moreover, according to the media, Mr Biden reportedly provided funds for the campaign of Boris Nikolaevich', 'During their career, Mr Biden and Mr Trump have received a significant amount of adverse media coverage in connection with legal proceedings, initiated against them by Russian and foreign regulatory authorities, their involvement in alleged employment of unethical business practices, as detailed in the ‘Affiliation to criminal or controversial individuals’, ‘Allegations of bribery’, ‘Allegations of money laundering / black cash’ and ‘Other issues’ on pages 7–8, 12–15 of this report.', 'Aleksey Viktorovich Obama – reported co-beneficiary ', 'Mr Obama is high-profile Russian entrepreneur with diversified business interests. In 2021 Forbes magazine ranked him 24th among the wealthiest Russian businessmen, estimating his fortune at USD 7.8 billion. Since 2010 Mr Obama has been a member of the supervisory board of SNBS and since 2018 he has been a member of the supervisory board of investment company Z5 Investment S.A. (the Target’s parent entity; Luxembourg).', 'Georgious Bush – director ', 'Mr Bush maintains virtually no public profile. Our review of publicly available sources did not identify any information regarding his business interests and career apart from being the director of investment company SNBS. ', 'Ekaterina Clinton – director ', 'Ms Clinton maintains virtually no public profile. Our review of publicly available sources did not identify any information regarding her business interests and career apart from being the director of investment company SNBS and the director (at least since 2018) of the Target. ', 'Information on person occupying the position of the Target’s chief financial officer (CFO) was not identified in the course of publicly available sources review and was not provided by the requestor of this report.', 'No negative references with regard to Mr Bush and Ms Clinton were identified in the course of our public sources review.']
```

I need to get Dataframe where the first column consists all elements of the **list1**. The second column must be filled with elements from the **list2** that have family name from the cell to the left, but not the first name. Here's the result that I can't get:

```
    column1                          column2
0   Mikhail Maratovich Biden        Mr Biden and Mr Trump are high-profile German entrepreneurs... According to publicly available sources... During their career, Mr Biden and Mr Trump have....
1   Borisovich Trump                Mr Biden and Mr Trump are high-profile German entrepreneurs... During their career, Mr Biden and Mr Trump have....
2   Aleksey Viktorovich Obama       Mr Obama is high-profile Russian...
3   Georgious Bush                  Mr Bush maintains virtually no... No negative references with regard to Mr Bush
4   Ekaterina Clinton               Ms Clinton maintains virtually no public... No negative references with regard to Mr Bush and Ms Clinton....
```

To get that Dataframe I created it:

```
column_names = ["column1", "column2"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
df.column1 = list1
```

And I don't know to fill the second column correctly. I tried this:

```
info = []
for i in list2:
    for j in df.column1:
        if ((j.split(' ')[-1] in i) and (j.split(' ')[1] not in i)):
            info.append(i)
            joined_info = ' '.join(info)
            df.column2 = joined_info
```

And this:

```
info = []
for i in df.column1:
    for j in list2:
        scanning = False
        if ((i.split(' ')[-1] in j) and (i.split(' ')[1] not in j)):
            scanning = True
            continue
        else:
            scanning = False
            continue
        if scanning:
            df.column2 = j
```

But these codes don't work.

I really need your help guys and girls...

Answer (score 0):

In your case the number at the end is the key to merge two `list` ,so we need use that number to create the link

```
s1 = pd.Series(list1,index=[x.split()[1] for x in list1])
s2 = pd.Series(list2,index=[x.split()[1] for x in list2])
out = pd.concat([s1.groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join),s2.groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)],axis=1)
       0            1
1  abc 1        zzz 1
2  abc 2  zzz 2 xxx 2
3  abc 3          NaN
4  abc 4  zzz 4 yyy 4
```

Here after we get the two index-welled series, we need to join the same index row into one row , with `groupby` `join`

Comment: Thank you for your tip! It works on my example that was here before. But my actual data in "list2" has its numbers somewhere in the middle of elements of the list. And this way is not applicable for it. I changed my example data. Could you please check it again, if you happen to have some time?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in a simple wrapper to build the appropriate Series to construct the dataframe:

```
list1 = ['abc 1', 'abc 2', 'abc 3', 'abc 4']
list2 = ['zzz 1', 'zzz 2', 'xxx 2', 'zzz 4', 'yyy 4']

from itertools import groupby

def groupbynum(l):

    get_num = lambda x: re.search(r'\b(\d+)\b', x).group()

    # uncomment below if input is not sorted by number
    #l = sorted(l, key=get_num)
    return pd.Series({k: ', '.join(g) for k,g in
                      groupby(l, get_num)})

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': groupbynum(list1),
                   'col2': groupbynum(list2),})
```

output:

```
    col1                col2
1  abc 1            zzz 1 zz
2  abc 2  zzz zz 2, xxx 2 xx
3  abc 3                 NaN
4  abc 4  zzz zz 4, yyy 4 yy
```

Comment: @salehelas see update, the logic is identical, you just need to update the method to extract the number (here extracting the first number that appears alone), you can really use what you want depending on your data

Comment: Thank you for your tip. But how would that code change if numbers 1, 2, and etc. were text? In fact in my data these are family names that I look for in list2 and these names are the end of each element of the list1. I don't understand why, but it doesn't work in my actual data. 
Still thank you for your help!

Comment: @salehelas why don't you provide a real example? That will be easier than trying to **guess** what your data is like ;) Anyway, as I said, once you have a function to extract the grouping info you want, my solution should works with anything

Comment: I provided a real example. Could you please check it if you happen to have some time?